# USB Speakerphone disconnects when I play sound

Tags: usb, audio

I have a USB speakerphone, Poly Sync 20, to be exact. When I connect it to my Windows machine through the USB hub, Windows will detect it but the moment I try to play sound it will instantly disconnect. There is no problem like this when plugging the device directly to a USB port on the motherboard.

I'm guessing it's because the USB hub does not have enough power. How can I confirm my assumption is correct? So if I want to fix this, would I need a USB hub that is powered? Would a Thunderbolt port have this power issue?